# Edit two models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my event controllers I edit some parameter of the event model but also on my user model.

the value I get in my controllers are corrects. but just the value of the event model are save

in my event model I have among other things :

```
    public Guid? UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User_ss { get; set; }



[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Achat( Event @event)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.Entry(@event).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            @event.NbpartId = @event.NbpartId - @event.NbFormId;



            var c = (@event.Budget * (@event.NbFormId));


            var Userprofiluser = (from s in db.Users
                                   where    s.PersonEmail.Contains(User.Identity.Name)

                                   select s).ToList();
            db.Entry(db.Users.Find(Userprofiluser[0].UserId)).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

            var P = (Userprofiluser[0].Wallet) - c;
            db.Entry(db.Users.Find(Userprofiluser[0].UserId)).State = EntityState.Modified;

            db.Entry(@event).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I see where you modify Event values, but not where you modify user values.

Comment: Find the `event` first from DB, just like what you are doing for `User`. Then  change the values of a event, then do a save.

Comment: What about you create a view model to combine event and user in a way that you will have both models data when the form is submitted.

Comment: Your was right Marc, I just have to had Userprofiluser[0].Wallet= P;